# Rule to change ubercart role expiration when role is granted

Tags: rules, ubercart

I need to 'standardize' the expiration date of a ubercart role as soon as the role is granted. I think I understand what the events and conditions should be. I can't figure out how to create the action, though.

In pseudo-code, I want to set expiration_date = 10th day of following month. Mathematically, that's easy enough. I assume the action will be to 'Set a data value'.

I use the selector to get to expiration:expiration. I get an error message that "The selected data property doesn't support writing." Is there any way to make it writable?